# Cross Account AWS Cognito Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have Cognito pool in account (11111111) with a lambda trigger for PreSignUp where the lambda function is in account (22222222). Im able to create the Cognito pool successfully however when I try to execute an action such as CreateUser I get the error `UnexpectedLambdaException: PreSignUp invocation failed due to configuration.`

I've updated the lambda resource policy to allow cross account access with the following statements:

```
{
      "Sid": "xaccount",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:22222222:function:my-function"
}
```

and

```
{
      "Sid": "AllowCognitoInvoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:22222222:function:my-function",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:11111111:userpool/*"
        }
      }
 }
```

Not sure what other configuration Im missing. Has anyone successfully setup something similar before?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my question. AWS support confirmed that you cannot configure Congito triggers to call lambda functions in a different account.

You can setup cross account lambda triggers on a Pool using the cli but you cant do it via the AWS Console. So if you do end up using the cli to setup cross account lambda triggers just know there is no way to invoke those fucntions.

In the end, I replicated the lambda trigger functions in the same account as the Cognito pool

Comment: Anyone else had any update on this, does aws allows keeping cognito and lambda trigger in seperate aws account.

Answer (score 0):

You can.

You just need a AWS Service > Other policy, pointing to your account cognito.

(tip: you can use * if you want to give more than one userpool access to the triggers)

I just tested it and it works.

[image: cross-account-trigger]

Comment: I wanted to understand more about how you got this to work.  I am far from a AWS expert, but dabble and am experiencing this problem.

If I understand correctly, this allows the Cognito account to call the Lambda function in the other account.  But how did you tell Cognito to call the Lambda in the other account?  I figured using an ARN, but I can't figure out how to specify an ARN with respect to the Cognito triggers.