# Keeping Cognito and lambda trigger in separate aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cognito

I have 2 aws account Account A and Account B.
Account B contains my cognito user pool.
Account A has lambda created.

Now I want to use lambda from Account A to be used as trigger for cognito in Account B.
I have created role in Account A, that assume role from Account B. 
**Trust Relationship**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-B-ID:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "xxxxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Permission Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:Account-A-ID:function:LAMBDAFUNCTIONNAME
        }
    ]
}
```

Though I still don't see the lambda in cognito trigger section.
Am i missing something, let me know if you guys have any solution.

I know it is recommended to keep your identity service (Cognito) and other backend service (i.e lambda, apigateway etc.) in seperate aws account.

Comment: You will basically never *see* cross account things in the AWS UI, not how things work. How would AWS know which lambda to show?? Maybe it works via APIs / IaC but even that depends on the specific service. *"I know it is recommended to keep your identity service (Cognito) and other backend service (i.e lambda, apigateway etc.) in seperate aws account."* - citation needed. And what does the assume-role have do with anything here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71086241/2442804

Comment: I have see the link you have posted @luk2302 , but I wanted to know even with cli whether it is possible to keep lambda and cognito in seperate account, because as per the comment on the link you posted "if you do end up using the cli to setup cross account lambda triggers just know there is no way to invoke those fucntions."

Comment: That answer sounds like it is not possible.